# useAppSelector Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm a beginner at typescript , in my component function I was trying to extract the value of the intialState from the redux slice as follows

```
const index = useAppSelector((state) => state.review.index);
```

the problem I getting squiggly line under state.review with the below message

```
(property) review: unknown
Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
```

Not understanding what's the case for review to be unknow even though I defined index in the slice as follow

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { data } from "../data/Reviews";
import { ReviewStateProps } from "../models/types.types";

const initialState: ReviewStateProps = { index: 0 };

const reviewSlice = createSlice({
  name: "review",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    nextPerson: (state) => {
      let newIndex = state.index + 1;
      if (newIndex > data.length - 1) {
        state.index = 0;
      }
      if (newIndex < 0) {
        state.index = data.length - 1;
      }
      return state;
    },
    prevPerson: (state) => {
      let newIndex = state.index - 1;
      if (newIndex > data.length - 1) {
        state.index = 0;
      }
      if (newIndex < 0) {
        state.index = data.length - 1;
      }
      return state;
    },
  },
});

export const reviewActions = reviewSlice.actions;

export default reviewSlice.reducer;

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import reviewReducer from "./rev.ts";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { review: reviewReducer },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

appreciate to point for me what's the issue here.

edit:
addressing on how I imported useAppSelector

in App.tsx

```
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from "./store/index";
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

then imported it in different components using the following

```
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from "../App";
```

Comment: Can you please who how do you import useAppSelector ?

Comment: @JulienKode  i have edited my question to address your comment , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to create the root reducer with `combineReducers` to plug them into the store:
https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers

Make also sure you file is a TS file and not a JS file

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: combineReducers({ review: reviewReducer }),
});
```

Comment: just did it but the issue is still persisting

Comment: Is it possible to have a codesandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-sound-8el56c?file=/src/store/index.js

Comment: Have you try to rename the store file src/store/index.ts ?

Comment: silly me , than you very much

Comment: I've update the answer